# Mathematica 8 won't launch on Fedora

Tags: warning-messages, linux, kernel-startup

I installed Mathematica on Fedora 31. Installation went fine. No errors. When I start Mathematica from temrinal, I see the banner, GUI opens up, and I see an error in the terminal :

> There was an error trying to initialize the HPI library. Could not create the Java virtual machine.

The kernel wont start. No statements can executed from yhr GUI.

I can start the mathKernel separately in the command line and it works perfectly. I can see that it executes.

```sh
$java -version
```

> ```
> openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
> ```

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate if addressed to Wolfram Support, rather than here.